# redirection issue nginx to haproxy to tomcat

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I am having issue like this. if i am using tomcat port in nginx configuration then application is running fine.Alternatively if i use ha-proxy port in nginx configuration and redirect requests to tomcat port from nginx then setup is not working and 503 error is occurring for the application.Below are my nginx and haproxy configuration files and detail of tomcat/ha-proxy ports.

Application is distributed and below is tomcat port description

```
/cas running on tomcat port 10039
/service running on tomcat port 10040
/running on tomcat port 10038
```

Below is detail of nginx ports used

```
 105 forwards request to 10039
 106 forwards request to 10040
 107 forwards request to 10038
```

Below is the content of nginx configuration file.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example-wh-qa.example.com;
    charset utf-8;
    rewrite     ^(.*)   https://$server_name$1 permanent;
  }

 server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server.key;
    server_name example-wh-qa.example.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example-warehouse-qa-error.log;
    charset utf-8;
    root /webroot-wh;

    location ~ ^/cas/(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:105;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    location ~ ^/service/(.*)$ {
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
            proxy_connect_timeout 300;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:106;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:107;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
            proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    }


   }
```

And below are content of haproxy file

```
global
    maxconn 200
    daemon
    #nbproc 8
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 warning
    log-send-hostname example.com
    defaults
    mode http
    log global
    timeout client 10m
    timeout server 10m
    timeout connect 4s
    option httpclose # Disable Keepalive
    option http_proxy
    balance roundrobin # Load Balancing algorithm
    option httpchk
    option forwardfor
    option redispatch
    option srvtcpka
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix
    stats enable
    stats refresh 10s
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats auth username1:passwd1
    stats auth username2:passwd2
    listen app1-proxy
    bind 127.0.0.1:105
    appsession JSESSIONID len 52 timeout 45m
    server app localhost:10039 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check cookie app1

 listen app2-proxy
    bind 127.0.0.1:106
    appsession JSESSIONID len 52 timeout 45m
    server app localhost:10040 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check cookie app2

 listen app3-sso-proxy
    bind 127.0.0.1:107
    appsession JSESSIONID len 52 timeout 45m
    server app localhost:10038  weight 1 maxconn 1024 check cookie app3-sso
```

Now in above content of nginix configuration file if i replace haproxy ports in "proxy_pass"  with tomcat ports directly then application is running fine but if i am using haproxy in between then application starts throwing 503 error on accessing the same.

As an additional information if i run application individual modules locally on server using tomcat ports like

```
elinks http://localhost:10039/cas/login  it works
elinks http://localhost:10040/service   it works
elinks http://localhost:10038   it works
```

but running them on haproxy port does not works except for last link.

```
elinks http://localhost:105/cas/login  it does not works
elinks http://localhost:106/service   it does not works
elinks http://localhost:107   it works
```

I seriously need to configure haproxy as to load balance my application in production.Please help me on this configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you finally figured it out. Something I saw missing in the settings

```
proxy_set_header    X-NginX-Proxy           true;
```

and

```
proxy_pass xx//localhost:106/service/;
```

and similarly for `xx//localhost:105/cas/login/`. Note the ending of URL with '/'